# Summary page and passing intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one form in which user must write some info and send to mysql database. What I trying now is to make new activity which after the user submit the form to load and display what he just submitted - an Summary page.
In this Activity I get all the info from previous activity and user send data to DB. Then I try to pass info to `Summary.class`

```
    btnFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);

    btnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
                Email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email");
        }

            new SummaryAsyncTask().execute((Void) null);
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(TableInformation.this, Summary.class);

            newActivity.putExtra("Name", Name);
            newActivity.putExtra("Email", Email);
            Log.d("Information to summary", Name + " " + Email);
            startActivity(new Intent(Information.this, Summary.class));
        }
```

And this is what I have currently in `Summary.class`

```
String getName;
String getEmail;

TextView nameOfPerson, emailOfPerson;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.summary);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        getName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
        getEmail = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Email");
    }   
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameOfPerson)).setText(getName+"");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailOfPerson)).setText(getEmail+"");
}
```

And the `summary.xml` contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameOfPerson"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailOfPerson"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result now is `NULL` on both `textview`. Can anyone help whit this?

Comment: from which activity you are getting  `getIntent().getExtras` on `btnFinish` Button Click?

Comment: From another activity. Until here all is good and when I click finish all data is saved in DB. Just can't pass info to next Summary activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new intent while starting the activity. It seems like a error.

Instead of

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(TableInformation.this, Summary.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("Name", Name);
        newActivity.putExtra("Email", Email);
        Log.d("Information to summary", Name + " " + Email);
        startActivity(new Intent(Information.this, Summary.class));
```

do this

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(TableInformation.this, Summary.class);
        newActivity.putExtra("Name", Name);
        newActivity.putExtra("Email", Email);
        Log.d("Information to summary", Name + " " + Email);
        startActivity(newActivity);
```

If you have any query please comment.

Comment: Ah, yes.. I see now where I have mistaken. It's all good now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is You don't set bundle to activity on first activity before calling start activity

By the way initialize bundle variable like
Bundle extrabundle = new Bundle();